# Javascript innerText adds two \n for every carriage return key user pressed

Tags: javascript, angular, textarea, innerhtml, innertext

Im my Angular project i have a textarea from which the innerHTML is read and characters count remaining shown to user

The from the same textarea i read text via innerText and send to server with length to store in DB.

```
Here innerHTML is : "hi<div><br></div><div>k</div><div><br></div><div>gh</div>" - Length 9
     innerText is : "hi\n\n\nk\n\n\ngh"  - Length 11
```

This is an issue when user enters maximum characters in textarea and when reading via innerText it exceeds that max limit when more carriage returns are used in paragraph.

I need both length to be in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your HTML includes two line breaks between each section.

Using `<div>...</div>` separates content onto a new line. Additionally, the `<br>` within the `<div>` creates a second new line.

It seems like your input is literally:

```
hi

k

gh
```

And if this was represented in a single line it would be literally: `hi\n\nk\n\ngh` because you have two breaks between each line.

If you want some alignment between the HTML and text formats, you will want to:

- Update the way you calculate length for `innerHTML` to be more accurate

or

- Replace two line breaks with one using `innerText.replace(/\n\n/g, '\n')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
.replace(/\n/g, '')
```